# How to correct (Wicket in) Tomcat at /myapp behinds Apache proxy at / that send incorrect redirect to /myapp/xxx instead of /xxx?

Tags: apache, tomcat, servlets, wicket

I have deployed my Wicket app at /myapp in Tomcat, and I have put it behind Apache web server using

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/myapp/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/myapp/
```

Now Wicket incorrectly redirect users to /myapp/xxx instead of /xxx.

Is there any way to make Wicket(1.3.5) use / as my root path (instead of /myapp which is servlet deployment context path)?!

Edit: There is a solution described at following link but it doesn't works for 1.3.5 version:
I found it: https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/wicket-behind-a-front-end-proxy.html

Edit: The problem is that wicket uses relative path redirects with ServletResponse#sendRedirect and Tomcat convert them to absolutes redirects containing /myapp at beginning. I have tried mod_jk(AJP) but there was no difference!

There should be some way to tell proxy-pass or mod-jk to rewrite redirects before sending them to client!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find this Tomcat document helpful:

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/proxy.html

It addresses the above situation with RedirectMatch and mod_rewrite.

Comment: On that page following section is the solution: 2. Use mod_headers to rewrite any HTTP redirects your application might return. ... Header edit Location ^([^/]*//[^/]*)?/(.*)$ $1/myapp/$2

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find direct answer but used following workaround with mod jk, I guess it is also possible to do with proxy pass.

```
RewriteRule           /myapp/(.*)      /$1 [L,R]
RewriteRule           ^(.*)            /myapp$1 [PT]
JkMount               /myapp/*         ajp13_worker
```

First line **redirects** request coming from client starting with /myapp/* (which are result of incorrect Wicket/Tomcat/Apache redirects) to /*.

Second line **rewrites** all requests from /* to /myapp/* and third line send them to tomcat.

For proxy pass, third line should be replaced with:

```
ProxyPass             /myapp/          http://localhost:8080/myapp/
ProxyPassReverse      /myapp/          http://localhost:8080/myapp/
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested myself, but have you looked at mod_rewrite? There are some examples describing what you want to do [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/proxy.html).

Comment: Yes, but I didn't figure out how to rewrite redirects, or how to tell tomcat how to convert relative redirect urls correctly.